# how to cache retrived data from online DataBase?

Tags: android

I have an application that reads information of songs and singers from Mysql DB and display it in listView ... my question(s)

1. is it a good idea to cache the data that the user already retrieved so he does not need to retrieve it every time?
2. how to do that chasing if it is a good idea(give me hints only)?
3. how to match between what is already cached and what is need to be retrieved from Mysql

Comment: Since the question-title says "from online DataBase?", I'm assuming you're accessing the data by using an API? Or are you really talking about the SQLite Database on the device itself?

Comment: yes MySql through PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to cache values coming from external sources, as it reduces the time the application takes to display them.

This can be implemented in multiple ways. Generally said:

- Binary data (e.g. Images) should be cached on internal/external storage. See ["Caching Bitmaps"](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
- Textual data (e.g. Articles) should be cached in memory (for example in a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html))

That said, the important and tricky part of a caching system is to determine, when a cached values is no longer "new" enough. While choosing the specific criteria depends on your application and personal taste, here are some general hints:

- The age of the data (you can give server-side hints with the [HTTP Response-Header `Expires`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses))
- The priority of the data. The more important the data, the more up-to-date it should be.
- The likelihood of any changes at all. The comments on a article are more likely to change frequently than the article itself.

---

A nice implementation would be to just delegate all network requests to a caching-aware method/class (implemented from the above hints), which would then decide if the request needed to be done in the first place and return either fresh or cached data.